# Use SwiftUI GeometryReader without affecting outer frame?

Tags: swiftui

Is it possible to use `GeometryReader` in such a way that it doesn't just fill up the parent view?

As a specific example, I want to control a bottom margin using `.padding(.bottom, geometry.safeAreaInsets.bottom > 0 ? 0 : 12.0)`.  This would use the safe area as the margin on iPhone X and a custom margin on older devices.

Without the `GeometryReader` my view takes up space appropriate to its actual vertical size.  *With* the reader the view takes up 1/2 the screen.

```
    VStack {
      Spacer()
      GeometryReader { proxy in // Lays out nicely without this...
        HStack {
          Text("Wrong")
          Spacer()
        }.border(Color.gray, width: 1)
      }
```

[image: Incorrect Layout][image: Desired Layout]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just add the `.fixedSize()` modifier to your HStack. That will achieve the desired affect.

Comment: `fixedSize()` works in that example, and attaching `fixedSize(horizontal:vertical:)` to my `GeometryReader` worked in the `View` I was actually working on (had nested `ZStack`s).

Answer (score 17):

You can also try adding `.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)` modifier to `GeometryReader`.