# SwiftUI GeometryReader compact size

Tags: swiftui, geometryreader

I would like my `LoadingTitle` to have a width of 70% of the screen so I use the `GeometryReader` but it makes the vertical size expand and my `LoadingTitle` takes much more vertical space. I would like it to remain as compact as possible.

When using hardcoded `width: 300` I get the correct layout (except the relative width):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            LoadingTitle()
            Color.blue
        }
    }
}

struct LoadingTitle: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack() {
                Color.gray
            }
            .frame(width: 300, height: 22)
            .padding(.vertical, 20)
            .border(Color.gray, width: 1)
    }
}
```

[image]

Now if I wrap the `body` of my `LoadingTitle` in the `GeometryReader` I can get the correct relative size but then the `GeometryReader` expands my view vertically:

```
struct LoadingTitle: View {

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            HStack() {
                Color.gray
                    .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.7, height: 22, alignment: .leading)
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding(.vertical, 20)
            .border(Color.gray, width: 1)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

I tried using `.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)` on the `GeometryReader` as [other suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56524226/use-swiftui-geometryreader-without-affecting-outer-frame) but then the resulting view is too much compact and all its paddings are ignored:

[image]

How could I achieve the layout of the 1st screenshot with a relative width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is possible approach. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4 (w/ ContentView unchanged)

[image: demo]

```
struct LoadingTitle: View {

    var body: some View {
        VStack { Color.clear }
            .frame(height: 22).frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .padding(.vertical, 20)
            .overlay(
                GeometryReader { geo in
                    HStack {
                        HStack {
                            Color.gray
                                .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.7, height: 22)
                        }
                        .padding(.vertical, 20)
                        .border(Color.gray, width: 1)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
            )
    }
}
```

Comment: nice, thanks. I believe we can also use a `Group` instead of the `VStack` and remove the outer `HStack` from the `GeometryReader`

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a fixed height for title,

```
struct LoadingTitle1: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            HStack {
                Color.gray.frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.7)
                .padding(.vertical, 20)
                .border(Color.gray, width: 1)
                
                Spacer()
            }
        }.frame(height: 62)
    }
}
```